# MVC and the use of a UIButton to dynamically create UI elements

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

I understand the concept of MVC. At least I hope I do but there is a particular situation that I have encountered recently that makes me think that I actually have no idea.

**Problem:**
I am trying to create a class that when applied to an existing button adds the functionality of editing that button's title. It does so by dynamically generating a UITextField that will in turn be populated with the Button's new name. I hold the logic of adding the UITextField in a class called CustomAnimation and initializing it in the following way:

```
CustomAnimation *yar = [[CustomAnimation alloc] initWithButton:customButton];
```

The problem that I encounter is when I am trying to dynamically create a UIButton from a custom class like CustomAnimation and try to assign a target/action to it. Since the UIButton is actually generated inside the ViewController FROM the CustomAnimation class the former should get a pointer to the parent ViewController and then set it as the target.

```
[classButton addTarget:viewController action:@selector(dostuff:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

All is good except one thing - **dostuff** method should reside inside the ViewController in order to be visible for that button and here everything turns into a hack.

*What is the correct approach when you want to generate temporary UI elements from inside a Class instead of the Controller?*

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can look at MVC in terms of granularity. If I understand your question correctly you are trying to implement MVC at a single control level which is - in my opinion - too finely grained. I try to aim for a more coarse approch where a controller manages a chunk of UI controls, e.g. a view or a window.

You could argue that the editability of the buttons label is bahavior that belongs to the button (encapsulated by it), hence its implementation is or should be part of the overall implementation of the button. Once you accept that, you could implement this as a subclass of UIButton and move the code that is in CustomAnimation to your subclass of UIButton. Or encapsulate CustomAnimation in your subclass of UIButton, whichever is more appriopriate.

Comment: This is a very good idea indeed, Roger. Though it doesn't entirely answer my question it gave me a great lead and this is what I was looking for. Thanks!